# Where can I find documentation for shell commands?

Tags: shell, terminal

For using a shell commands through a terminal program, where can I find documentation or help or man pages for the commands *as implemented in Android*?

While it would be nice to have them on the device via *man*, PDF or web-based would be fine, too.

When I run "man" from terminal, I get an error and I haven't found a good source online.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619993/available-linux-commands-across-android-versions

Comment: @CiroSantilli华涌低端人口六四事件法轮功 - The link provided is a question more on the list of available commands than on man pages for them. And the answers are rather poor.

Comment: An old related question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647014/how-can-i-get-information-from-the-shell-about-commands-available-in-android-she

Answer (score 8):

You may have a look at http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html for a description of busybox and the commands provided by it. 
And trust me, if you are going to do work in the console, you probably want to use busybox.

Comment: it is to be noted that stock Android does not come with `busybox`, and instead uses `toolbox`.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the terminal commands in android are the limited version of standard Linux/Unix/POSIX terminal commands, provided by the `toolbox` program. Notably absent from `toolbox` is the `cp` (file copy) command, you must use `cat file1 > file2` instead. If you spend a lot of time in the shell, you may want to install `busybox`, which provides a richer set of standard POSIX commands.

There some bit about android shell here: http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/13/android-under-the-hood

Answer (score 3):

Since I stumbled over the same problem as you did I started to compile [a list of useful commands in the Android Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11052/what-useful-android-shell-commands-do-you-know) including examples. A [German version](http://www.osfight.de/archives/1544) is on my blog.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of "standard" Android shell commands are found in /system/bin/ and the majority of those are symlinked to Toolbox, a bsd licensed set of applets, similar to busybox, but without the GPL-2 licensing ""issues"". Toolbox helps Google's need to remove dependence on GPL code, and is targeted to small size and specific Android tasks. It was not meant for end-user use.

There is no builtin manuals in stock android, and toolbox applets lack any documentation, from the commands, from toolbox itself, and online. They are very limited copies of what most users would consider the standard POSIX type tools. More similar to the BSD-Utils, so BSD Util flags are more likely to work and behavior is more similar to BSD-Utils than it is Posix. Even then, Toolbox applets lack many of those flags.

The closest thing to documentation is the source code. Which, like most of Android, available online. Here is the Froyo version of the Toolbox source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/froyo/toolbox 
Just find the version you need.

Keep in mind, different manufacturers might change the code. Samsung's Toolbox is different from Motorola's. Heck, Samsung Galaxy S Toolbox differs from Samsung Sidekick 4g (Galaxy S based). Manufacturers might add applets for their own use, or change the default for specific purposes. the `restart` applet in toolbox will work on the phone it came on, but the busybox `restart` applet will not, unless specifically patched. `Time` and `Date` are also different. There are others as well. So Toolbox isn't something you can completely replace with Busybox or the full GNU-Utils or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

## On older Android versions

On older Android versions, shell commands tend to be either:

- Rewritten specifically for Android, and shipped as part of Toolbox. I'm not sure whether or not Toolbox is really documented anywhere.
- Or copied from NetBSD. If so, then the command was recompiled for Android, and the command (but not its manual page) is shipped with Android.

Use `type` to tell you where a command is stored, and `ls -l` on the command to tell you whether it's a real binary or a symbolic link. If it's a symbolic link to Toolbox, then you'll know that the command is part of Toolbox.

A few commands, such as `kill`, are available both as a shell builtin (this is the version which will normally run) and in `/system/bin` (this version will normally never be run). `type` will tell you which version will run.

## On Marshmallow and up

Android 6.0 "Marshmallow" and up ship with [Toybox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toybox), and most of the most commonly used shell commands (`cp`, `mv`, `ls`, et cetera) tend to be Toybox toys.  Toybox toys normally include built-in help; official manual pages are not included.

Still, Toybox doesn't include everything, and so not everything is provided by Toybox.  For example, even on Android 6.0 "Marshmallow", [`fsck_msdos`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/fsck_msdos/+/master) (which should only be used to check SD cards of 32 GB or less) appears to be taken from either FreeBSD or NetBSD.  `fsck_exfat` (which can check most SD cards 64 GB or larger) is taken from elsewhere.  I'm not sure where.

## Your shell

On modern versions of Android, the shell is `mksh`, the MirBSD Korn shell.  If `mksh` is running, then to find out your `mksh` version, enter:

```
echo $KSH_VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting an Android Virtual Device (AVD), connecting to it with adb, and running the Android shell command in question:

```
pdurbin@macbook ~$ cd /Applications/eclipse/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools
pdurbin@macbook platform-tools$ ./adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# /system/bin/pm
usage: pm [list|path|install|uninstall]
       pm list packages [-f]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
       pm list instrumentation [-f] [TARGET-PACKAGE]
       pm list features
       pm path PACKAGE
       pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f] PATH
       pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE
       pm enable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm setInstallLocation [0/auto] [1/internal] [2/external]
[snip]
```

If anyone knows the flag to give Android shell commands to just print the usage screen, please let me know.  I tried --help, -help, -h, --usage, etc.

Try to run `ls /system/bin` and see also http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands

Answer (score 1):

The set of shell commands used by Android seems to be `toolbox`.
Information on it seems to be not centralized (which seems *obscure* to me), but one could search and find pieces of information around, e.g.

http://www.all-things-android.com/content/android-toolbox-command-reference

For "intensive" use of the command line, [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) is generally recommended as a replacement for `toolbox`.

Credits / Related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647014/how-can-i-get-information-from-the-shell-about-commands-available-in-android-she

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498651/how-to-execute-the-help-linux-command-on-android

https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference