# When using a terminal emulator, why are there so many normal Linux commands that do not work?

Tags: command-line, terminal

There are a lot of standard Linux commands that do not work from a Terminal Emulator in Android. I thought Android is based on the Linux kernel, but it lacks so many functions like `man`, `groups`, `find`, etc.

Why are there so many normal Linux commands that do not work?

Comment: A kernel does not implement the binaries, as you should know. The latter are stored in **/system/bin**, **/system/xbin** or **/sbin**.

Comment: If you need additional commands, check for "[Busybox](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_991)". Though its installation usually requires root access, there's at least one that does not.

Comment: This is similar to asking why applesauce does not have a crust, because apple pie and applesauce are both based on apples.

Answer (score 3):

This is not Bash. At the beginning of my journey in Android, I have seen that the Android shell is a little bit different from Bash.

### The Android Shell

A "shell" is a program that listens to keyboard input from a user and performs actions as directed by the user. Android devices come with a simple shell program. This shell program is mostly undocumented. Since many people are curious about it, I thought I'd write up some documentation for it.

### Built-in Commands

Every shell has a few built-in commands. Some common built-in commands are:

- `echo` -- prints text to stdout
- `set` -- sets shell variables
- `export` -- makes shell variables available to command-line programs
- `cd` -- change the current directory
- `pwd` -- print name of the current directory

### Futher Reading

Please check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-shell-commands) question and [this](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference) page for more details.

Comment: Android uses [mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/false.htm). Here's an interesting read: http://www.all-things-android.com/content/mirbsd-korn-shell-android-shell