# Samsung FRP lock - Android 5.1 have access to Settings

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, frp

Not a duplicate as per other threads, due to the final step, `Go to Backup and Reset and do a Factory Data Reset. As per my other answer, this will remove FRP from the device`. The FRP lock is still there in my issue.

I have tried the methods listed here: [How to bypass "Verify your account" (Factory Reset Protection)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127739/how-to-bypass-verify-your-account-factory-reset-protection)

FRP lock on Samsung S5 Neo

Android 5.1

Have full(ish) access to device

Using various methods, 5.1 Samsung camera download trick in this instance, I have access to Settings, and the rest of the phone. This is the 2nd time I have got to this stage as the first time, I followed the tutorial and did `Settings > Backup and reset > Factory reset > Erase everything`; but the FRP lock was still on!! Even though it isn't in the videos.

I have now got to a stage again where I have device access, but this time I wanted to enable Developer options to enable ADB and force the change in the settings/secure Content Provider, however enabling dev options tapping Build Number doesn't work!!

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a duplicate, as I have tried those methods and it doesn't work for me. the final step is "Backup and reset > Erase everything". My FRP lock stays activated even after doing this step!

Comment: [Enable ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154437/131553) may work but it needs root

Comment: Already tried to flash stock Marshmallow, same issue; but there is another workaround on MM using RealTerm and the dialler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly... I'm not 100% but here goes....

After fiddling around, flashing a custom bootloader (which got blocked due to FRP lock) I reflashed 5.1 stock ROM and did the camera trick for the 3rd time, however I got boot loops and so the phone started up in Safe Mode.

I then restarted the phone to get out of Safe Mode and the FRP Lock was disabled. I had done nothing different except that the phone booted itself into Safe Mode. After Safe Mode and normal reboot, Settings/Build Number taps worked fine whereas it previously hadn't. I believe Safe Mode to be the crucial step to disable FRP Lock/Google verification.... Now need someone to verify.

Manual way here:

- Power off the device.
- Press and hold the Power key for one or two seconds to turn on the
  device.
- When the Samsung logo displays, press and hold the Volume down key
  until the lock screen displays.   When the Lock screen is displayed,
  Safe mode is displayed in the lower-left corner of the screen. To
  exit Safe mode, restart your device.

TLDR; FRP Lock/Google verify > Boot into Safe Mode, then reboot again into normal mode > FRP Lock gone?

The only extra step was that it rebooted into Safe Mode from a privileged state, e.g. I had a lockscreen setup.

Comment: Hell yes this worked for me on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A6!!

Comment: could you add what version your Tab A6 was running when this worked please